# Vue JS pass a value inside to a CSS property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm developing an exams portal application.

[image]

and this is my code.

```
<div class="" v-for="areas in knowledgeAreas">
        {{areas.area}}<div class="progress"  style="margin-top:10px;">
          <div class="progress-bar"  style="width:50%">{{areas.correctlyMarkedAnswers}} out of {{areas.numberOfQuestion}}</div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

and

```
data(){
    return{
      knowledgeAreas :[
        { area: 'Math',numberOfQuestion:10,correctlyMarkedAnswers:3,correctAnswersPercentage:12 },
        { area: 'IQ',numberOfQuestion:10,correctlyMarkedAnswers:5,correctAnswersPercentage:5 },
        { area: 'GK',numberOfQuestion:10,correctlyMarkedAnswers:8,correctAnswersPercentage:3 }
      ]
    }
  }
```

What I want is to dynamically pass the `correctAnswersPercentage` property's value to the CSS width property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created `getProgress` method then pass the value of `correctAnswersPercentage` during iteration.

Please check the snippet below:

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
      knowledgeAreas :[
        { area: 'Math',numberOfQuestion:10,correctlyMarkedAnswers:3,correctAnswersPercentage:50 },
        { area: 'IQ',numberOfQuestion:10,correctlyMarkedAnswers:5,correctAnswersPercentage:60 },
        { area: 'GK',numberOfQuestion:10,correctlyMarkedAnswers:8,correctAnswersPercentage:70 }
      ]
    },
    methods: {
     getProgress: function(width) {
       return {
          'width': width + '%',
          'background-color': 'yellow'
        };
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="" v-for="areas in knowledgeAreas">
        {{areas.area}}<div class="progress"  style="margin-top:10px;">
          <div class="progress-bar"  v-bind:style="getProgress(areas.correctAnswersPercentage)">{{areas.correctlyMarkedAnswers}} out of {{areas.numberOfQuestion}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PathumSamararathna Np, glad to help.